# Testing with Gradle

Tags: java, testing, gradle

Testing fails.
How fix exception?
Here is stacktrace and code:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':test'.
Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

My parent settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'opti'
include 'web'
```

build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    group 'com.opti'
    version '1.0'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    dependencies {
        testCompile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11',
            'org.spockframework:spock-maven:0.7-groovy-2.0'
    }
}
```

Tested module settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'web'
include 'web'
```

build.gradle

```
group 'com.opti'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(':web'))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Artur check that first: 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

It seems that gradle could not find default configuration for web project.

You could also check if running this command helps

```
gradle :opti:test
```

or

```
gradle :web:test
```